# How can MATLAB function wavread() be implemented in C++?

Tags: c++, matlab

How do I implement the MATLAB function `wavread` in C++?

It means read a [WAV](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/WAV) file into a vector array.

Comment: What do you mean by "to C++"?

Comment: Are you wanting to *call it from* C++ or *re-implement* it in C++?

Comment: Wavread simply imports the .wav file's information into the Matlab environment. Are you asking for a similar process for C++?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you want to do it in C++, there are two options. Use a library, or write your own function that can extract information from WAV files. Several C/C++ libraries such as [Juce](http://www.rawmaterialsoftware.com/api/classWavAudioFormat.html#_details), [SDL](http://www.libsdl.org/cgi/docwiki.cgi/SDL_LoadWAV) etc. have functions/classes that can read WAV files. This is probably total overkill for your case. If you want a simple(ish) library specialised to read audio files, [libsndfile](http://www.mega-nerd.com/libsndfile/) sounds (pun not intended) like a good bet. If you *must* roll your own implementation, a description of the WAV format in C can be found [here](http://www.wotsit.org/list.asp?page=4&fc=12&search=&al=) (Warning: The link leads to a page that allows you to download a zipped MS Word file).